# Sideways table placement gets deferred more than expected

Tags: tables, positioning, rotating

The problem I have is basically articulated in this [thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4391).  According to the veteran respondent, it appears that sideways table does not support placement specifications.  However, its behaviour should nonetheless be predictable.

Now the compiled code below should give you a 4-page doc.  I have filled the document with dummy text in blocks coloured differently so we can see what is happening.  The first block is one page and a bit over.  Ok, so the sideways table should start on the first page after the preceding black text has cleared, no problem.  So I expect the sideways table to appear on page 3.  Instead it waits till after the next block yet (blue) is complete, *then* it kicks in and tacks my table onto the end on page 4.  It should not wait until after the blue text clears entirely because the blue text chronologically comes *after* the table.  If black text is on the page, then fine, even a little, it has to be deferred to the next page.  But it should continued to be deferred if there is *only* blue text, as the blue text comes after the table.

How do I make the table appear on page 3 only after the preceding black text has cleared?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption} %apparently needs to come first or options clash with other packages will occur

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}%to enable sideways table
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\caption{}
\label{}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X X X X X}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Time of induction (\SI{}{\minute})} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG + Chloramphenicol} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{Lactose} &  \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG (\SI{5}{\micro\Molar}) + Glucose} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG (\SI{10}{\micro\Molar}) + Glucose} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG + Rifampicin} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}X}{IPTG + Streptomycin}\\
\midrule
0   &   0.057   &   0       &   0               &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
1   &   0.060   &   0.003   &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
2   &   0.069   &   0.012   &   \num{5.0e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
3   &   0.083   &   0.026   &   \num{1.1e-6}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
4   &   0.120   &   0.063   &   \num{2.6e-6}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
5   &   0.123   &   0.066   &   \num{2.8e-6}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
7   &   0.191   &   0.134   &   \num{5.6e-6}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
10  &   0.310   &   0.253   &   \num{1.1e-5}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
12  &   0.399   &   0.342   &   \num{1.4e-5}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
15  &   0.491   &   0.434   &   \num{1.8e-5}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
30  &   1.179   &   1.122   &   \num{4.7e-5}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
45  &   1.585   &   1.528   &   \num{6.4e-5}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
0c  &   0.056   &   0       &   \num{0}         &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
15c     &   0.057   &   0.001   &   \num{0}         &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
45c     &   0.055   &   0       &   \num{0}         &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}    &   \num{1.3e-7}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\textcolor{blue}{\Blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Changing the following line moves the table from Page 4 to Page 3 as desired:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
```

The `p` says to place the figure on a page containing only floats (which the `sidewaystable` requires anyway).

See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) for more details on float options, especially the document [Using Imported Graphics in LaTeX and pdfLaTeX](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) which mentions on Page 54 that it is better to provide more float options.